# SQL – How to find all entries that are missing certain expected criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in a factory that makes microchips.

The Microchips are made in batches of 10,000 – and the final stage of their manufacture involves them going through a machine that Inspects them in various ways.

Shown below is a sample table for Microchip number 1 from Lot ID 1402361301.

| LOT_ID | MICROCHIP_SERIAL | INSPECTION_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 35 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 36 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 37 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 38 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 39 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 40 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 41 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 42 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 43 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 52 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 53 | 1 |
| 1402361301 | 1 | 49 | 1 |

As can be seen from the table, there are a total of 12 Inspection IDs. The last one is Inspection_ID 49.

From my knowledge, any Microchip with a Status of 1 and Inspection_ID 49 should have the other 11 Inspections.

How can I use SQL to show me entries with Status 1 and Inspection ID 49 that are missing any of these 11 Inspections?

(Bonus: Can I select entries that are missing all 11 Inspections, missing any 1 Inspection or missing 1 Particular Inspection?)

Comment: Does 'missing' mean that one of the inspections are not present in the data at all or can it be there with a STATUS = 0?

Comment: Missing means it is not present at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` and use conditional aggregation to find the lots that have the correct inspection and status and a count of their inspections:

```sql
SELECT lot_id,
       COUNT(*) AS num_inspections
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY lot_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN inspection_id = 49 AND status = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

If you want to find lots with inspection 49 and status 1 that have fewer than 12 inspections:

```sql
SELECT lot_id,
       COUNT(*) AS num_inspections
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY lot_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN inspection_id = 49 AND status = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(*) < 12
```

If you want to check if a specific inspection was missing then:

```sql
SELECT lot_id,
       COUNT(*) AS num_inspections
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY lot_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN inspection_id = 49 AND status = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN inspection_id = 35 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for this!

One thing I should have mentioned /clarified, is that there are a total of 12 Inspection IDs for every single Microchip for every single Lot.

So one Lot ID (like 1402361301) in the table above - will have 10, 000 Microchips - and each Microchip in this lot, that has an Inspection ID of 49 and Status of 1, should have the 11 other Inspections.

Is there a method of me getting to the level of granularity to show me every single Microchip and it's associated Lot ID that had an Inspections ID of 49 and a Status of 1 - that was missing any of the other 11 Inspections?

Comment: @JohnCampbell Change it to `GROUP BY lot_id, microchip_serial`?

Answer (score 0):

Cross join the inspections with the completed inspections. Then use `NOT EXISTS` to find which inspections are missing from your table.

```
with
  completed as
  (
    select lot_id, microchip_serial
    from lot_inspection
    where inspection_id = 49 and status = 1
  )
select c.lot_id, c.microchip_serial, i.inspection_id
from completed c
cross join inspection i
where not exists
(
  select null
  from lot_inspection li 
  where li.lot_id = c.lot_id 
  and li.microchip_serial = c.microchip_serial
  and li.inspection_id = i.inspection_id
)
order by c.lot_id, c.microchip_serial, i.inspection_id;
```

I expect there to be an inspection table, as you have a column called inspection_id. If not, then create one one-the-fly or in the database. If there is an inspection table, but it holds additional insepection IDs, then use another CTE to only select the desired IDs.