Multiple values of column in where condition
I have a table as below
create table auto
(
  ID number,
  SEQ number,
  COLUMN_NME varchar2(10),
  RELATIONAL_OPERATOR varchar2(20),
  COLUMN_VALUE varchar2(20)
);

insert into auto SELECT 1,1,'HONDA','=','ACCORD' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 1,2,'ENGINE','=','V6' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 1,3,'COLOR','=','BLACK' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 1,4,'COLOR','=','BLUE' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 2,1,'TOYOTA','=','SIENNA' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 2,2,'COLOR','=','BLACK' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 2,3,'ENGINE','<>','V6' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 3,1,'HONDA','=','ODYSSEY' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 3,1,'COLOR','<>','BLACK' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 3,1,'ENGINE','=','V6' FROM DUAL;
insert into auto SELECT 3,1,'HONDA','=','CRV' FROM DUAL;

I need the results where

column_nme = 'HONDA', COLUMN_VALUE = 'ACCORD'
COLUMN_NME= 'COLOR', COLUMN_VALUE = 'BLACK'
COLUMN_NME = 'ENGINE' , COLUMN_VALUE  = 'V6'

(CONSIDERING ALL RELATIONAL_OPERATOR IS '=')
I tried writing using case statement
select ID,SEQ,case when column_nme = 'HONDA' and column_value = 'ACCORD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HONDA,
 CASE WHEN COLUMN_NME = 'ENGINE' AND COLUMN_VALUE = 'V6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ENGINE,
 CASE WHEN COLUMN_NME = 'COLOR' AND COLUMN_VALUE = 'BLACK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END COLOR
 FROM AUTO;

I need the ID of this table where HONDA = 1, ENGINE = 1 AND COLOR = 1

I've changed the tag plsql to sql. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language, which is not involved here. You are looking for a solution in SQL.

Your EAV data looks a bit weird, by the way. You are looking for cars where the engine is V6, the color is black and the Honda is Accord. One would rather store MAKER= HONDA, MODEL=ACCORD or the like, so as to search for cars where the engine is V6, the color is black, the maker is Honda and the model is Accord.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142135/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/35506607/1509264

Your table auto is an EAV (entity attribute value) table, and you want the IDs matching all of three criteria:

HONDA = ACCORD
COLOR = BLACK
ENGINE = V6

The typical approach to query EAV tables is via aggregation: Get all IDs having all required matches:
select id
from auto
group by id
having count(case when column_nme = 'HONDA'  and relational_operator = '=' and column_value = 'ACCORD' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when column_nme = 'COLOR'  and relational_operator = '=' and column_value = 'BLACK'  then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when column_nme = 'ENGINE' and relational_operator = '=' and column_value = 'V6'     then 1 end) > 0;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/NEDty7pP

Maybe a little bit easier to read and maintain:
select id
from auto
where (column_nme, relational_operator, column_value) 
in (
    ('HONDA', '=', 'ACCORD'),
    ('COLOR', '=', 'BLACK'),
    ('ENGINE', '=', 'V6')
)
group by id having( count(*) >= 3 )
;

And if you don't have unique constraints on the triple:
select id from (
    select distinct id, column_nme, relational_operator, column_value
    from auto
    where (COLUMN_NME, RELATIONAL_OPERATOR, COLUMN_VALUE) 
    in (
        ('HONDA', '=', 'ACCORD'),
        ('COLOR', '=', 'BLACK'),
        ('ENGINE', '=', 'V6')
    )
)
group by id having( count(*) >= 3 )
;

(having( count(distinct column_nme, relational_operator, column_value) is not valid syntax...)

If the OP does not have a UNIQUE constraint on those columns then this may match duplicates of one triplet and fail to match one-or-more of the other triplets and be returned (unexpectedly) as a false-positive. COUNT(DISTINCT ...) may solve that.
